# How do you associate objects to objects of the same type in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model of `Blocks` in a table (also `blocks`).

I want to make it so each `Block` can be associated to one or many other `blocks` as both parent and children.

So each Block could need (?) both `'belongs_to'` and `'has_many'` other blocks.

I tried creating a migration like this

```
class AddChildrenToBlocks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_reference :blocks, :children
  end
end
```

That successfully added a column for "ID's" in my blocks table but I have a feeling that doesn't 'know' it's an object, it's just adding an ID column as it would for 'anything'.

Is it possible to create a reference/association in Rails where an instance of an Object can have many (or no) children/parents of other Objects of the same type?

A simple example might be :

Block 1 : Parent (Block 3, 2) Children (Block 4, 5, 6)

Block 2 : Parent (Block 7) Children (Block 10, 11, 12)

Comment: Self-referential assocations aren't that different then any other one-to-many associations which is what you're actually confused about. `references` should always be singular as you're storing a single integer pointing to the id of another row (the parent_id in this case).  Trying to store a `has_many` assocation in a single column is pretty common beginner hangup caused by the object-relational-impedence-missmatch. AR is an object oriented abstraction around SQL but you still need to think in terms of relational database design.

Comment: what is the alternative to storing in a single column though? storing each 'child' in it's own column?

Comment: You don't need an alternative if what you're looking to do is a one-to-many assocation. Neither is there one. Noobs often fall into the trap of trying to use an array or json type column to store many id's (the id for each child) but that doesn't work with ActiveRecord assocations, violates 1NF and doesn't allow the use of foreign key constraints to maintain referential integrity. You just have to get your brain wrapped around thinking in relational terms.

Comment: @Yakov's answer explains what you need code wise but this is more the why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each block can have a parent.

```rb
add_reference :blocks, :parent
```

For each `parent` you can find all its `children`

```rb
belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Block', foreign_key: :parent_id, optional: true
has_many :children, class_name: 'Block', foreign_key: :parent_id
```

Comment: You might want to add the `inverse_of:` option here since it most likely cannot be automatically derived.

Comment: Thank you so much this makes sense - does that second bit go in the model of Block?

Comment: Yes it should be inside the model.